# how to get debit in account_move_line

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I want  when i select compte_id his 'debit' will be display in a field named 'montant_compt ' the account_id and debit are stored in 'account_move_line' 
you can understand by code :

1- i add  two fields in my class

```
class AccountMove(models.Model):
_name = 'account.move'
_inherit = 'account.move'
compte_id=fields.Many2one('account.account',string='Compte Budgétaire')
montant_compt=fields.Char('Montant compte')
```

2- this step to get debit of account_id:

```
@api.multi
def get_debit_account(self,compte_id):
    montant = ""
    for line in self.line_id :
        if self.compte_id == line.account_id.id:
           montant = line.debit
           return {'value': {'montant_compt': montant}}
```

3- in my file .xml

```
 <field name="compte_id" on_change="get_debit_account(compte_id)"/>
```

but it isnt working , please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you need to remove *_name = 'account.move'* Because we are adding field on existing *account.move* object.
2. *line.debit* store float value. So we need to declare *montant_compt* field as float.
3. no need to write *onchange* in xml side. With new api we can directly access via following code.
4. *account.move* object don't have *line_id* it's *line_ids*
5. When we check any condition, make sure have same type of value on right hand side as well as left hand side. For example: you have written: *self.compte_id == line.account_id.id:* where right hand side has integer type value and left hand side has browse object type value.

Try with following code:

```
class AccountMove(models.Model):
_inherit = 'account.move'

compte_id=fields.Many2one('account.account',string='Compte Budgétaire')
montant_compt=fields.Float('Montant compte')

@api.onchange('compte_id')
def onchance_compte_id(self):
    for line in self.line_ids:
        if self.compte_id == line.account_id:
            self.montant_compt = line.debit
            return
```

For more details [Odoo ORM API Reference Documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/reference/orm.html)